# SharePoint Desiginer 2010 - Workflow starts another workflow

Tags: workflow

Since you can't loop back in a workflow, I'd like my workflow to branch to another workflow if it reaches a point where it would need to go back. Is there an option to have my workflow start another workflow?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check this page? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/f97edf9f-d0c6-4f78-a91f-db53231b4961

Comment: I was able to resolve my situation following this post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-start-a-child-workflow

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) and particularly [Start Another Workflow](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Start%20Another%20Workflow&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: I second this approach. We have used this activity in several production workflows. I would point out, though, you may need to consider a 1 minute wait on the child workflow so that the parent has time to fully exit.

Answer (score 1):

Having a pair of workflows triggering each other is a common way to build loops in SharePoint Designer.

Since your workflow starts when an item is changed, you just need to have the first workflow modify a field. This will trigger the second workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Even am facing the same issue. On item update, SP 2010 designer workflow will not re-initiate or there is no default action to start another workflow or the same (which was avail in SP 2007 designer WF).

Can go for custom workflow activities else can use event handlers hopefully.

Looping back, infinite looping are all possible if you will check on some particular field's value from the workflow.

Can get a clear view in this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/eda805e6-f363-4006-983d-89cee1551d6b